# Automatically sending to Print (using CutePDF Writer)

Tags: export, interoperability, pdf-format, printing

I use CutePDF for creating PDF output, but this requires manually selecting Print (Ctrl+P), with CutePDF Writer as the printer, and pressing OK.  Can this be automated?

Comment: Can't you Save or Export as PDF using only Mathematica ?

Comment: If I do `Export["page.pdf", page]` my output is bigger and inferior quality than if I print to CutePDF Writer. If I could direct my export through CutePDF that would be great.  Can this be done?

Comment: Can't you set CutePDF as the default printer?

Comment: @ Sjoerd - That wouldn't seem to help automation, unless I can print automatically.(?)  I think I would need to set CutePDF as my default `Export` PDF writer, but there's doesn't seem to be an option for that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include a side-by-side comparison of the two outputs as it may be possible to improve the quality of `Export`.  An interesting question though. +1

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard - I'll get round to that presently, but I definitely want to use the CutePDF writer automatically.

Comment: not sure if this qualifies as answer: Set CutePDF the default Printer. Then use NotebookPrint and probably you seem to need Custom PDF "Writer with programmatic access" from http://www.cutepdf.com/Solutions/pdfwriter.asp

Comment: Rolf's answer is what I had in mind when I asked the above question. NotebookPrint prints to the default printer. Just add a macro in the keyboard settings file and you're done.